# How can I measure power dissipation of a component while sweeping a square wave?

Tags: power, ltspice, frequency

I'd like to measure the power dissipation of my MOSFET as the driving frequency changes. I have a DC (PULSE) voltage source to simulate the FET driver, and I would like to measure the FET's power dissipation as I sweep the driving frequency from 100 to 100 kHz.

Searching around, it seems like power is only measured during a transient analysis, but I'm not sure how to sweep the frequency for the DC PULSE source.

[image: Circuit for MOSFET]

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be to run multiple transient simulations with TON and period of the voltage source defined in-terms of a variable say {freq} and sweeping the freq using .STEP param